# central limit theorem for high dimensional random walk

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-walk, probability-limit-theorems, central-limit-theorem

Consider random walk in $\mathbb{Z}^d$, $d>1$, with $x(t) = x(t-1) + \xi$, where $\xi$ has some probability distribution in $\mathbb{Z}^d$ with finite support, expectation $m = \sum_{v \in {\mathbb{Z}^d}} P(\xi=v) v \, \, \in\mathbb{R}^d$.

What is the central limit theorem formulation for the variable
$S_t = \frac{x(t) - mt}{\sqrt{t}}$? More precisely, how is distributed $S_{\infty}$? Is it simply the gaussian integrated with respect to every coordinate? How to define the variance for an probability distribution in $d>1$ dimensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The central limit theorem in multidimensional space is Theorem 3.9.6.
 (page 151) 
in the fourth edition of *Probability: Theory and Examples* by 
Richard Durrett. You can get a free copy of the book at 
http://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf